# work_item.fields['System.StateChangeDate'] is giving keyerror

Tags: python, azure-devops

I am creating a connection to the Azure DevOps organization with the PAT and getting the work item tracking client. Then looping through the work items and retrieve their details. When I execute the code, it throws the below error:

> 'StateChangeDate':work_item.fields['System.StateChangeDate']
> KeyError: 'System.StateChangeDate

Code:

```
for work_item_ref in query_results.work_items:
work_item = wit_client.get_work_item(work_item_ref.id)
results.append({
    'ID': work_item.id,
    'Title': work_item.fields['System.Title'],
    'AreaPath': work_item.fields['System.AreaPath'],
    'IterationPath': work_item.fields['System.IterationPath'],
    'WorkItemType': work_item.fields['System.WorkItemType'],
    'State': work_item.fields['System.State'],
    'Tags': work_item.fields.get('System.Tags'),
    'CreatedDate': work_item.fields['System.CreatedDate'],
    'ChangedDate': work_item.fields['System.ChangedDate'],
    'StateChangeDate':work_item.fields['System.StateChangeDate']
    })
```

what has to be done to fix this error?

Comment: `work_item.fields` does not have `System.StateChangeDate` key. Please check what are the keys of `work_item.fields`. You can do this by printing it: `print(work_item.fields)`